# Change VMWare SCSI in Redhat

Tags: redhat, vmware-workstation, vmware-vsphere

I have a VMWare Redhat machine that I need to change the SCSI controller on the machine from a  LSI Logic Parallel to LSI Logic SAS. I have done this through vmware, but now when the box tries to boot it kernel panics saying that it cant mount /dev/root

Can anyone help with this as I am unable to find much information on it and really dont want to rebuild the machine.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If it's RHEL 5 or 6, then don't use any of the two LSI controllers in virtual machine definition. Use the paravirtualised storage driver.

See [this](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1010398) VMware KB article for the supported configurations and migration procedure.

Answer (score 1):

The LSI Logic SAS virtual controller is really only there for Windows 2008 to allow for clustering. Use one of the other virtual controllers instead.

Comment: We are getting better performance on this controller rather than anything else...so thought the logical step would be to move controllers?

Comment: Check this; http://virtualizationeh.files.wordpress.com/2010/10/vsci.jpg

Answer (score 1):

In RHEL 7.x this is a bit different as modprobe.conf doesn't exist.
In my case I needed to change the controller for the root disk from Paravirtual to LSI Logic SAS.  As the previous posts suggest, this needs to be done in two places, the regular disk and the RamDisk as both will need to boot with the new driver.
First, if possible, clone your machine, don't snapshot it.  Whenever you are working with disks, it's best not to involve snapshots.
You may not need to do this second step, I did it in the theory that the disk controller would initialize itself if introduced to the system through an additional disk, just like you'd do for Windows:
Second step - Shut down your VM, Attach a 1 GB disk using the SCSI controller type you'd like to change your root disk to and bring the system back up to modprobe discover it.  (You might be able to do this hot)
Third step - run the following command to add the correct driver to the RamDisk (Remember in my case I was moving from the VMWare Paravirtual to the LSI Logic SAS driver.  It's likely you are going the opposite way, but you just need to change the driver type:
dracut -f -v --add-drivers mptsas

Other options for drivers are:
mptspi
mptscsih
mptbase

After doing this, shut down and remove the 1 GB temporary disk.
Change the controller for the root disk to whatever driver you just added to the ramdisk, and boot up the system.

Comment: This worked fine for me

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, when the system boots up, an initial ram disk is created from the contents of a file which contains certain drivers the system needs to continue booting. If that initial ram disk file doesn't contain the drivers for your system, the system will not able to boot. To resolve this, you'll need to rebuilt the initrd file using the following procedure:

1. Boot the system into rescue mode from the installation disc and chroot /mnt/sysimage
2. Backup your /etc/modprobe.conf file and replace any scsi_hostadapter entries in it with the following:

   alias scsi_hostadapter mptbase
   alias scsi_hostadapter1 mptspi

Create an initial ram disk

1. cd /boot
2. mv initrd-*.img initrd-*.img.bak (replace * with actual file name)
3. mkinitrd -v -f /boot/initrd-*.img * (replace both instances of * with actual version number in the file you just renamed)
4. Reboot the system

If you need to revert for any reason, simply boot back into rescue mode and revert /etc/modprobe.conf and the initrd-*.img file, then reboot.

Answer (score 0):

After change to paravirtual the VM did not recognized a OS\BOOT disk.
We found that the disk on BIOS BOOT order was mismatch, and we need to update the order of those in VM BIOS.
Its happen even if we had less than 3 disks... The VM BIOS boot take just the first disk in the order.

*for more information read this VM discuss*
https://communities.vmware.com/t5/ESXi-Discussions/VM-Hard-Disk-Boot-Order-with-more-than-8-VHDs/td-p/2067783